# Filter on a date field not typed as a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to filter a field as date, but the field is not typed date or datetime.

```
SELECT champ_save_id, element_id, valeur
FROM g_champ_save AS cs
INNER JOIN g_champ AS c ON cs.champ_id = c.champ_id
WHERE cs.valeur <> '' AND NOT cs.valeur IS NULL
AND c.champ_code = 'qualif_valide_qualif_fin'
AND CONVERT(datetime, cs.valeur, 103) <= @filterdate
```

It throws an error (`Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string`) unless I comment the last line.
As I understand it, the SQL optimizer first executes the `CONVERT` function on every `valeur` field and , then filters on the other conditions, then joins. So it tries to `CONVERT` fields with "regular" text in it, so of course it does not work.

I tried with a CTE but it does exactly the same thing.

```
WITH valeurs AS (
    SELECT champ_save_id, element_id, valeur
    FROM g_champ_save AS cs
    INNER JOIN g_champ AS c ON cs.champ_id = c.champ_id
    WHERE cs.valeur <> '' AND NOT cs.valeur IS NULL
    AND c.champ_code = 'qualif_valide_qualif_fin'
    AND ISDATE(convert(datetime, cs.valeur, 103)) = 1
)
SELECT * FROM valeurs
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, valeur, 103) <= @filterdate
```

Do you have any idea which would allow me to be absolutely sure to *first* return the fields containing dates, and *then* filter them ?

The tables are designed like that (shortened for clarity) :

```
CREATE TABLE g_champ (
    champ_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    type_id int NOT NULL, -- defines the type : text, checkbox, date, etc
    champ_code nvarchar(50) NULL,
    champ_label nvarchar(max) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE g_champ_save (
    champ_save_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    champ_id int NOT NULL,
    element_id int NULL,
    valeur nvarchar(max) NULL
)
```

Thanks

Comment: CONVERT(datetime, cs.valeur, 103) caused error. Please check data in that column, value should be datetime i.e 2012013 or some date value string can be converted as DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use [IsDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx):

```
SELECT champ_save_id, element_id, valeur
FROM g_champ_save AS cs
INNER JOIN g_champ AS c ON cs.champ_id = c.champ_id
WHERE cs.valeur <> '' AND NOT cs.valeur IS NULL
AND c.champ_code = 'qualif_valide_qualif_fin'
AND CONVERT(datetime, case IsDate(cs.valeur) when 1 then cs.valeur end, 103) 
    <= @filterdate
```

Comment: +1 : Although that assumes the OP wants to ignore any values that fail to convert.  Seems more likely (to me) that the OP should use ISDATE() to find the offending records and then correct them, rather than ignore them?

Comment: From my understanding the `ISDATE()` function will return true if the value can be converted to date in any format, so this can still fail if the value can't be converted to 103 datetime format

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but IsDate() tests on american format (m/d/y), and my dates are in french/english format (d/m/y). So 31/1/2012 is not considered a date.

Comment: Thanks to @jontotetwoo (lower in the answers), I can now use IsDate with a d/m/y format. But it still throws the same error ; although, when I add a `when 0 then getdate()` clause in the "case", it works ! .... How can I mark both answers as right ? :P

Comment: @cosmo0: Upvote both answers, accept whichever was more helpful? :)

Answer (score 1):

try it in the `HAVING` clause and use `IS NOT NULL` not `NOT cs.valeur IS NULL`

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
GO
SELECT champ_save_id, element_id, valeur
  FROM g_champ_save AS cs INNER JOIN g_champ AS c 
         ON cs.champ_id = c.champ_id
 WHERE cs.valeur <> '' AND 
       cs.valeur IS NOT NULL AND 
       c.champ_code = 'qualif_valide_qualif_fin'
HAVING CONVERT(datetime, cs.valeur, 103) <= @filterdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I know this works for MSSQL and MySQL, but NOT sure what DB u r using

```
SELECT champ_save_id, element_id, valeur
FROM g_champ_save AS cs
INNER JOIN g_champ AS c ON cs.champ_id = c.champ_id
WHERE cs.valeur <> '' AND NOT cs.valeur IS NULL
AND c.champ_code = 'qualif_valide_qualif_fin'
AND Date(cs.valeur) <= @filterdate
```

Comment: Nope :/ `'Date' is not a recognized built-in function name.`. I use SQL Server 2005/2008.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do the job without conversion errors. Note: Invalid timestamps will be ignored.

```
SELECT
champ_save_id, element_id, valeur
FROM
(
SELECT champ_save_id, element_id, valeur
FROM g_champ_save AS cs
INNER JOIN (SELECT c.champ_id FROM g_champ c WHERE c.champ_code = 'qualif_valide_qualif_fin') AS c ON cs.champ_id = c.champ_id
WHERE cs.valeur <> '' AND NOT cs.valeur IS NULL AND ISDATE(cs.valeur)
) sub
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, cs.valeur, 103) <= @filterdate
```

**Update**

Made some changes and this returns the expected result.

SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

SELECT
champ_save_id, element_id, valeur, CONVERT(datetime, sub.valeur, 103)
FROM
(
SELECT champ_save_id, element_id, valeur
FROM (SELECT 1 champ_id, 1 champ_save_id, 1 element_id, '30/1/2012' valeur) AS cs
INNER JOIN (SELECT c.champ_id FROM (SELECT 1 champ_id, 'qualif_valide_qualif_fin' champ_code) c WHERE c.champ_code = 'qualif_valide_qualif_fin') AS c ON cs.champ_id = c.champ_id
WHERE cs.valeur <> '' AND NOT cs.valeur IS NULL AND ISDATE(cs.valeur) = 1
) sub
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, sub.valeur, 103) <= '01/02/2012'
```

Comment: No, apparently the subquery does the same thing as the CTE.